# Succincting multiple switch/case statements

Tags: android, loops, switch-statement, code-cleanup

Alright, I'm trying to succinct some code in my app. It works fine, I'm just a bit OCD and want to keep improving performance.

Here's what the code in question looks like now:

```
switch(ressound){
            case R.id.button40:
            ressound = R.raw.sound40;
            soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote40));
            break;
            }
               switch(ressound){
                case R.id.button900:
                ressound = R.raw.sound900;
                soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote900));
                break;
                }
               switch(ressound){
            case R.id.button901:
            ressound = R.raw.sound901;
            soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote901));
            break;
            }
```

It's a soundboard app, and this is regarding the save as feature in it. Is there any way to succinct these multiple statements (some screens have 40+ sounds)? Using a loop looks like an obvious choice, however after looking around, the case statement apparently has to be static and not a variable.

EDIT: Forgot to include the actual function header:

```
        public boolean function1(int ressound){  

              String soundname = "";
```

Comment: did u got any error here?

Comment: No, it works fine in my code. I just don't know how to make it so that for every button I won't have to make a separate statement

Answer (score 0):

```
int quoteval=0; 
switch(ressound){
            case R.id.button40:
            ressound = R.raw.sound40;
            quoteval =R.string.quote40;               
            break;
            case R.id.button900:
            ressound = R.raw.sound900;
            quoteval =R.string.quote900;
            break;
            case R.id.button901:
            ressound = R.raw.sound901;
            quoteval =R.string.quote901;
            break;

}
soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(quoteval));
```

Comment: Works (except I had to keep the last line within each statement; I need the strings from R.string.quote#; not R.raw.sound#), but I'm looking for any way I could do away with having to list each case statement for each button. Gets a little tedious changing all the numbers...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can use a loop and eliminate the switch-case statement. Use the [`Resources#getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Assuming you name your resources with sequential numbers ("sound_filename_1", "sound_filename_2", etc) you can write some code like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> findSoundResourceIds(Resources res) {
    ArrayList<Integer> resIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = 1;
    do {
        int resId = res.getIdentifier("sound_filename_"+i, "raw", getPackage().getName());
        if (resId == 0) {
            break;
        }
        resIds.add(resId);
        i++;
    } while (true);

    return resIds;
}
```